# Optional FileField Django

Tags: django

Overriding FileField to validate a CSV input file. Have a form and trying to provide user with option of entering simple queries as a comma-separated CharField and large requests as a CSV. I've tried required=False but I'm not sure how to pass it in the override method.

Ideally I would want to display an error saying "Enter something" if the CharField and FileField are both empty, process the CharField if the FileField is empty and always process the FileField if it's populated.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

forms.py

```
class userGroupForm(forms.Form):
    userGroup_entryList = MultiEntryField(max_items=10)
    userGroup_entryFile = CSVFileField(max_items=40)
    userGroup_queryType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('User','User'),('Group','Group')))
    userGroup_sourceType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('Corp','Corp'),('Prod','Prod')))
```

fields.py

```
class MultiEntryField(forms.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.max_items = kwargs.pop("max_items")
            super(MultiEntryField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    def to_python(self,value):
            if not value:
                    return []
            else:
                    entries = []
                    for entry in value.split(','):
                            entries.append(entry.replace(' ',''))
                    return entries
    def validate(self,items):
            super(MultiEntryField, self).validate(items)
            if len(items) > self.max_items:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - More than '+str(self.max_items)+' items')
            for item in items:
                    if re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_/.]',str(item)):
                            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - Only alphanumeric characters')

class CSVFileField(forms.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.max_items = kwargs.pop("max_items")
            super(CSVFileField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    def validate(self,file):
            super(CSVFileField, self).validate(file)
            if file:
                    if file._size >= 5000:
                            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - File bigger than 5KB')
                    if file.content_type not in ['application/vnd.ms-excel'] or os.path.splitext(file._name)[1] not in [".csv"]:
                            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - Not a CSV file')
                    try:
                            fileReader = csv.reader(file.file)
                    except:
                            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - Problem reading file')
                    fileList = []
                    for row in fileReader:
                            fileList.append(row[0])
                    if len(fileList) > self.max_items:
                            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - More than '+str(self.max_items)+' items')
                    for item in fileList:
                            if re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_/.]',str(item)):
                                    raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - Only alpanumeric characters')
            else:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR - No file to process')
```

Comment: drop the "else" in CSVFileField.validate?